# Vertical power transmission from top to bottom

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Is it possible to transmit the redstone power with a lever, vertically, and from top to bottom?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't transmit power with a lever because it can't recieve power. I think you mean something else...?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using the lever to turn the signal on/off.

The wiki has a [Vertical Pattern](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Circuits#Vertical_transmission) for transmitting the signal on it. For moving a signal from bottom to top it is simple. Put a torch on the stone the lever is one, then a stone above it with another torch upon that. It will scale up. For a down or up signal a 2x2 spiral is the next easiest manner in which to get a signal to travel. Note that depending on the distance you may need a repeater some where in the mix to get the signal to carry on.

Hope this helps